# Could Dark Matter be comprised of gravitational waves entrained in the bulk?

Tags: gravity, hilbert-space, quantum-entanglement, dark-matter

The evidence is strong that more massive galaxies have more massive Dark Matter (DM) halos (for example, Qi Guo et al, Monthly Notices of the Royal Astronomical Society, Vol 404 (2010)). Might this dependency of DM halo mass on baryonic mass be attributed to stronger gravitational fields?
The vacuum may be viewed as a manifold of highly entangled quanta of space-time embedded in a higher dimensional bulk. If the bulk is disentangled from the vacuum, then it may be modelled as an orthogonal Hilbert space (for example, M. Van Raamsdonk “Building up space-time with quantum entanglement” Gen Relativ Gravit 42 (2010)).
Radiation propagating at light speed may be modelled simultaneously in both the vacuum and bulk Hilbert spaces, as no time propagates in either space, viewed from the light frame.
Gravity propagates at light speed, and if gravity waves become entrained in the bulk, they could manifest as static particles exhibiting only gravitational properties, i.e. DM.
The greater intensity of gravitational radiation in more massive galaxies would result in greater entrainment, and consequently more DM. This dependency seems consistent with observation.

Comment: How would you test this hypothesis?

Comment: The dynamics of matter accretion over the history of galactic formation might be a factor that could explain DM halos.

Comment: Sure but how do you distinguish your exotic hypothesis from more mundane ones, like ordinary particles that don't interact with photons?

Comment: Gravity waves entrained in an orthogonal Hilbert space would appear completely static, and exhibit only gravitional properties i.e local space-time distortion. So the total absence of other physical properties might be the best way to distinguish.

Comment: What other physical property? You haven't defined any sort of observation or experiment.

Comment: If DM is entrained gravity, then presumably it doesn't react with ionizing radiation (beyond a gravitational interaction). This might provide some basis for observational experiments, comparing galaxies with similar DM halos but different radiation environments.

Comment: Inert particles would seem a more parsimonious hypothesis for a null result in that case.

Comment: Agreed. Galaxy formation is the only possibility, as this hypothesis provides for particle creation, and others don't.

Comment: Details, details. What instrument(s), how much exposure time, ...

Comment: Simulation models as described in Qi Guo et al might provide a good starting point. Physical assumptions about entrainment would be required e.g. what are the gravitational wave frequency and intensity dependencies. Cosmic events involving large gravitational disturbances might be viewed as particle creation events in such simulations.

Comment: Simulation models are no substitute for real experiments.

Comment: The results of simulations might lead to better focus on what experiments to consider.

Comment: You have not managed to convince me that there's a phenomenon here.

Comment: Perhaps the thermodynamic analogy of a heat engine might add support to this hypothesis. DM is clearly the largest energy storage in the universe, with 85% of all mass. Gravity can be viewed as the engine in this analogy. If gravity, through the generation of gravitational waves, sources DM (of any nature) then the vacuum is the working fluid. The extra assumption required here is that the vacuum/bulk combination is the working fluid.

Comment: Words. What experiment do you propose?

Comment: Cosmic events involving large gravitational disturbances would generate a DM residual (halo). So  detailed observations of gravitational lensing immediately subsequent to such events might detect their presence.

Comment: An increase in gravitational red shift would also occur.